# Scons failed to install TMV on Ubuntu 14.04 (for GalSim)

Tags: scons, galsim

I tried to install the TMV library (0.7.1) on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, before I can install GalSim package.  However, it just failed, and gave these information :

> scons: Reading SConscript files ...
>   Unknown variables: ['LINKFLAGS']

I am using Anaconda Python, and the scons version is: v2.3.4

And, on my MacOX 10.8 laptop, the same TMV library can be installed by the same version of scons without any problem

Thank you very much if you can help me about this!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to manually specify extra LINKFLAGS for some reason?  What are the flags set in your tmv_scons.conf file?  If LINKFLAGS is in there, you could try removing that and see if that works.

Comment: Hi, Mike!  Thanks for the reply.  You are right, I just noticed that the problem is caused by an extra "LINKFLAGS" in the "SCONSFLAGS" environmental parameter when I tried to install LSST pipline.